# Append auto-incrementing suffix to duplicated elements of a List

Tags: scala, list, suffix

Given the following list :

```
val l = List("A", "A", "C", "C", "B", "C")
```

How can I add an auto-incrementing suffix to every elements so that I end up with a list containing no more duplicates, like the following (the ordering doesn't matter) :

```
List("A0", "A1", "C0", "C1", "C2", "B0")
```

Comment: These elements are going to be sorted, correct?

Comment: Not necessarily, I've edited my question and answer to reflect that

Comment: OK, so you're now assuming like elements will be grouped, yes?

Comment: No, I make absolutely no assumption on the list

Comment: what algorithm are you trying to implement? is it some kind of BWT? or something ?

Comment: If the question is not clear enough please specify which part so that I could explain it better. I'm just adding suffixes to duplicated elements of a list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it out by myself just after having written this question

```
val l = List("A", "A", "C", "C", "B", "C")
l.groupBy(identity) // Map(A->List(A,A),C->List(C,C,C),B->List(B))
  .values.flatMap(_.zipWithIndex) // List((A,0),(A,1),(C,0),(C,1),(C,2),(B,0))
  .map{ case (str, i) => s"$str$i"}
```

If there is a better solution (using `foldLeft` maybe) please let me know

Comment: Important thing to note here is that you'll lose ordering because of the `groupBy`.

Comment: Again, I don't care about the ordering. I could simply `sortBy` at the end, not a big deal

Comment: I think this might be as good as it gets without introducing mutable state. I was thinking about a map of counts and trying a `foldRight` and decrementing the counts as you encounter elements, but that's not so nice.

Comment: I also started with `foldLeft` but got lost in the middle.

Comment: Nicely done. The `mapValues()` and `flatten` steps can be combined in a single `flatMap()` like so: `groupBy(identity).values.flatMap(_.zipWithIndex.map{case (s,i) => s"$s$i"})`

Answer (score 1):

In a single pass straightforward way :

```
def transformList(list : List[String]) : List[String] = {
  val buf: mutable.Map[String, Int] = mutable.Map.empty
  list.map {
    x => {
      val i = buf.getOrElseUpdate(x, 0)
      val result = s"${x.toString}$i"
      buf.put(x, i + 1)
      result
    }
  }
}

transformList( List("A", "A", "C", "C", "B", "C"))
```

Comment: Well, it's really a matter of taste and context at this point, both a mutable or an immutable map are usable here.

Comment: I agree that it's functionally the same. But you should make a function so you're not _exposing_ the mutability.

Comment: I guess why not ^^ Updated

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the most readable solution, but...

```
def appendCount(l: List[String]): List[String] = {
  // Since we're doing zero-based counting, we need to use `getOrElse(e, -1) + 1`
  // to indicate a first-time element count as 0. 
  val counts = 
    l.foldLeft(Map[String, Int]())((acc, e) => 
      acc + (e -> (acc.getOrElse(e, -1) + 1))
    )

  val (appendedList, _) = 
    l.foldRight(List[String](), counts){ case (e, (li, m)) =>
      // Prepend the element with its count to the accumulated list.
      // Decrement that element's count within the map of element counts
      (s"$e${m(e)}" :: li, m + (e -> (m(e) - 1)))
    }
  appendedList
}
```

The idea here is that you create a count of each element in the list. You then iterate from the back of the list of original values and append the count to the value while decrementing the count map.

You need to define a helper here because `foldRight` will require both the new `List[String]` and the counts as an accumulator (and, as such, will return both). You'll just ignore the counts at the end (they'll all be `-1` anyway).

I'd say your way is probably more clear. You'll need to benchmark to see which is faster if that's a concern.

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/jMau9Q).

Comment: I think using `groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.length)` would be better compared to the complexity of using Map accesses and dealing with `getOrElse`

Comment: The `getOrElse` calls in the `foldRight` are unnecessary. Edited. I think yours is more readable, but I think mine is faster.